# Mobile Usability report only shows 1 valid page since Google changed the crawler to smartphone

Tags: google-search-console

My website has all its content indexed, in fact coverage is showing 45 valid pages indexed:

[image: previous index coverage]

At some point, Google decided to change from Desktop to Mobile indexer and suddenly the Usability report showed a drop in the amount of valid pages there:

[image: new index coverage]

This is weird because I'm not seeing any errors. The site has no manual actions and all mobile usability tests say that everything is ok.

Does someone have a clue of what is happening?

Comment: What happens when you run your pages through Mobile Friendly Test? Are you seeing any correlating impact on site performance?

Comment: Everything looks fine, I've been testing many urls and all of them are fully loaded without any errors or warning